# How to set the priority of the methods that are included in groups in testng.xml file?

Tags: testing, testng

I have a class which has 2 methods. Each method is having a group associated.

Now I want to set my testng.xml file in such a way that when testcase TC1 executes, Method1() and then Method2() will be called and when testcase TC2 will be executed, Method2() and then Method1() will be executed.

Is there any way by which I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can move your test case methods to a helper class and then simply create a test class for each test case, define your methods with their test priorities and/or dependencies, and call your shared test method code. e.g.:

```java
public class TestCaseMethods {
    public static void method1() { /*...*/ }
    public static void method2() { /*...*/ }
}

public class TC1 {
    @Test
    public void method1() {
        TestCaseMethods.method1();
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"method1"})
    public void method2() {
        TestCaseMethods.method2();
    }
}

public class TC2 {
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"method2"})
    public void method1() {
        TestCaseMethods.method1();
    }

    @Test
    public void method2() {
        TestCaseMethods.method2();
    }
}
```

You can also use inheritance if you prefer:

```java
public class AbstractTC {
    public void method1() { /*...*/ }
    public void method2() { /*...*/ }
}

public class TC1 extends AbstractTC {
    @Override
    @Test
    public void method1() {
        super.method1();
    }

    @Override
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"method1"})
    public void method2() {
        super.method2();
    }
}

public class TC2 extends AbstractTC {
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"method2"})
    public void method1() {
        super.method1();
    }

    @Test
    public void method2() {
        super.method2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have 3 queries:  1.You are saying that for each TestCase, I need to create a TestClass ? 2. I wont be required to use groups features? 3. Can you tell me how would testng.xml file look.

Comment: Correct, groups will not be necessary. Your `testng.xml` file can be very simple. Basically include all of the classes and/or the package they are in. e.g. `<suite name="${suite.name}"><test name="${test.name}"><packages><package name="${package.name}"/></packages></test></suite>`.